# Time - How to say that a time range is not very large/ small?

Tags: adjectives, time, time-words

For example, when talking/writting to someone about when I'm available.

> This week I'll be available on Friday from 5PM to 6PM.
>    I know it's
>   not a **very wide/range range/lapse** but...blahblah

1) What's the correct way to express "very wide/range/lapse" when talking about time?

2) The same but saying that it's small instead of saying it's not large.

3) Are there commonly used expressions to say the same both in formal and informal contexts?

Comment: This isn't really your answer, but I'd phrase it, *"I know it's a tight schedule, but ..."*

Comment: *I know that's not very long*. OR *I know that's a pretty small window*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. While it's not the direct answer to my two questions it hits what I want to say perfectly. Could it be used both in formal and informal writing/speaking?

Comment: @rewobs In my opinion, "a tight schedule" can be used on any occasion in general, formal or informal. Here is an example taken from the Atlantic's Economy Summit on C-SPAN 3, April 2, 2012, *"I would like to reconvene our forum at this time. As you know, we are still on our tight schedule with one hour remaining on our second panel."* You can make it sound much less formal by adding a word like *pretty* or *fairly*, e.g. *"I know it's a pretty tight schedule, but ..."*

Answer (score 2):

Not a very

- [long](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/long_1) period of time
- long time [span](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/span_2)

And of course **short** as the opposite of long.

Sometimes

- [window of opportunity](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/window) is used meaning

> a short period of time that is available for a particular activity (LDOCE)

but without more context I'm not sure it fits your situation.

Or one can just quantify time as an uncountable noun:

- we won't have **much [time](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/time_1)** (look for definition 5)
- there won't be **[a lot](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lot_1) of time**

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about the 'length' of time -whether long or short, a common term that comes to *my* mind is -[duration](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/duration?q=duration)

> *the **length of time** that something lasts or continues*

When we speak about timings, we generally specify what we are talking about. In your case you have stated it as well.

Having said that,

> I'll be available ..... from... I know, it's a **short duration**, but somehow, we'll have to adjust with it.

We have many examples on short and/or long duration stating the length of the time. We often use it, don't we?